# Copy Cassandra table to Hive

Tags: cassandra, hive, tableau-api

I've been stuck on this problem for days. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to make a copy of cassandra table to hive (so that I can put it into hive metastore and then access it from Tableau). The Hive -> Tableau part works, but not the Cassandra to Hive part. Data isn't being copied to Hive metastore.

Here are the steps i've taken:

I followed the instructions from the README of this project: https://github.com/tuplejump/cash/tree/master/cassandra-handler

I generated hive-cassandra-.*.jar, copied it and cassandra-all-*.jar, cassandra-thrift-*.jar to hive lib folder.

Then I started hive and tried the following:

```
hive> add jar /usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0/lib/hive-cassandra-1.2.6.jar;
Added [/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0/lib/hive-cassandra-1.2.6.jar] to class path
Added resources: [/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0/lib/hive-cassandra-1.2.6.jar]
hive> list jars;
/usr/lib/hive/apache-hive-1.1.0/lib/hive-cassandra-1.2.6.jar
hive> create temporary function tmp as 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql3.CqlStorageHandler'
    > ;
FAILED: Class org.apache.hadoop.hive.cassandra.cql3.CqlStorageHandler not found
```

I don't know why hive can't see CqlStorageHandler ...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative you can consider is to write a simple java program to write the data to a file which you can then load to hive.

```
package com.company.cassandra;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.Builder;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSet;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Row;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class CassandraExport {

    public static Session session;


    public static void connect(String username, String password, String host, int port, String keyspace) {
        Builder builder =  Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(host);
        builder.withPort(port);
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            builder.withCredentials(username, password);
        }

        Cluster cluster = builder.build();
        session = cluster.connect(keyspace);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Prod
        connect("user", "password", "server", 9042, "keyspace");

        ResultSetFuture future = session.executeAsync("SELECT * FROM table;");
        ResultSet results = future.getUninterruptibly();
        for (Row row : results) {
            //Print the columns in the following order
            String out = row.getString("col1") + "\t" +
                            String.valueOf(row.getInt("col2")) + "\t" +
                            String.valueOf(row.getLong("col3")) + "\t" +
                            String.valueOf(row.getLong("col4"));
            System.out.println(out);
        }

        session.close();
        session.getCluster().close();
    }


}
```

Write the output to a file and then load to a hive.

```
hive -e "use schema; load data local inpath '/tmp/cassandra-table' overwrite into table mytable;"
```